# Bordered button with slated corner with CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve the bordered button with slated (with turned page effect) corner with CSS, example:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/dmxt/75Fkv/

HTML:

```
<a class="btn-note" href="#" role="button">gratis prøve</a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-note {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 5px #00ABE2;
    color: #00ABE2;
    padding: 10px 80px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.btn-note:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -2px;
   right: -2px;
   border-width: 30px 30px 0 0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #00ABE2 rgba(0,0,0,0);

}

.btn-note:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

Thanks, I hope I could get it answered. I've been trying for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-folded-corner-effect/

Comment: @Anthony It won't work for dynamic/photography background, but thanks for a try and edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to achieve this (using just pseudo-elements, if using addtional HTML elements, we even have more ways to go), each has its own advantage. I would like to introduce 2 ways. The first uses 2 pseudo-elements. The second uses multi-background feature together with **one** pseudo-element and the `calc` function (looks like browsers supporting multi-backgrounds feature should also support `calc` function, and only ***IE8*** is considered to be a fairly old browser which does not support these features).

**1. The first solution**:

```
.btn-note {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 5px #00ABE2;
  border-right:0;    
  color: #00ABE2;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;    
}
 /* render the triangle corner */
.btn-note:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  bottom:-5px;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
}
 /* render the right border */
.btn-note:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:30px;
  left:100%;
  top:-5px;
  bottom:25px;
  border-width:5px 5px 0 0;
  border-color:inherit;    
  border-style:solid;
}
.btn-note:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;   
}
body {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600);
}
```

### [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/t9m9m/).

**2. The second solution**:

```
.btn-note {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 5px #00ABE2;
  border-right:0;
  border-bottom:0;
  color: #00ABE2;
  padding: 10px 80px 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background:linear-gradient(to top, #00abe2,#00abe2),
             linear-gradient(to left, #00abe2, #00abe2);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:calc(100% - 30px) 5px, 5px calc(100% - 30px);
  background-position: left 0 bottom 0, right 0 top 0;
}

.btn-note:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
}

.btn-note:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to top, #fff,#fff),
                   linear-gradient(to left, #fff, #fff);
}
body {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600);
}
```

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/75Fkv/2/).

The difference between the 2 solutions is, while the text can be spreaded the whole inner width of the bounding box (with 5px border) using the second solution, the first solution limits the text just inside the actual width of the `.btn-note` which is about `30px` distant from the right edge of the bounding box. That means the second solution is a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.btn-note:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -5px;
   right: -5px;
   border-width: 30px 30px 0 0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #00ABE2 black;
}
```

In your "rgba(0,0,0,0)" you set the black border to transparent, and the blue from the main rectangle showed through.

EDIT:

Ok How about this Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) method?

```
<svg height="200" width="400">
      <polygon points="0,0 400,0 400,150 350,200 0,200"
               style="fill:none; stroke:#00ABE2;stroke-width:15"  />
      <polygon points="350,150 400,150 350,200" 
               style="fill:#00ABE2;stroke:#00ABE2;stroke-width:10" />  
      <text x="50" y="100" fill="#00ABE2" font-size="3em">Gratis</text>
</svg>
```

JS Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyclopeus/6mW58/)

W3 Schools Tutorial: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp)

This SVG stuff may not be supported in older browsers.

Comment: I hoped that I would be more clear... sorry. `border-color #00ABE22 black;` is valid for black background, but I wanted to put that button on actual photography background. I couldn't find how to get `black` part to transparent.

Comment: Can we use HTML5 and JavaScript? I don't think you can do it with just CSS. HTML5 might not be supported by older browsers.

Comment: Maybe try something like this SVG [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyclopeus/6mW58/). You'll have to play around and get the points in the right places, get the size right, that sort of thing. There is a tutorial at W3schools here [link](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="note">
    <div class="innerNote">
        Your Content
    </div>
</div>

.note {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.note:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 25px 25px 0 0; /* you can manage the size of corner here*/
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue #fff;
}
.innerNote{
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/75Fkv/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with different background. I wanted to add photo background. :(

http://jsfiddle.net/dmxt/Ek276/1/

Thanks for trying, though!

Comment: You have to manage the `background`.  Make changes here `border-color: blue #fff;` change the border from `#fff` to your respective `background`

Comment: Its not possible for multiple backgrounds. You have to manage the `border-color` as per your `background-color` to get that corner effect

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works very fine. The green background can be replaced with an image background and it should work fine.

```
.green_background{
     background:#009966;width:200;
 height:100;
 padding:30px 10px 10px 10px;
 font-family:sans-serif,verdana,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
}
.example_holder{
  background:#000000;
  float:left;
  padding-top:20px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #00ccff;
  border-right: 0px solid #00ccff;
  border-left: 4px solid #00ccff;
  border-top:4px solid #00ccff;
  margin-right:0;
  color:#ffffff;
  height:40%;
  width:77.8%;  
}
.top_right_corner{
   float:right;
   background:#000000;
   border-right: 4px solid #00ccff;
   border-left:0px solid #000000;
   border-top:4px solid #00ccff;
   margin-left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   width:18.8%;
   height:22%;
 }
 .bottom_right_corner{
  float:right;
  background:transparent;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
  border-right: 21px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #00ccff;
  border-top:20px solid #00ccff;
  bottom:0px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  }
```

You need to be careful with the size of borders and widths of each element. Check a [working example](http://elimukwanza.ac.tz/example.html)

```
<div class="green_background">
<div class="example_holder">Example</div>
<div class="top_right_corner"></div>
<div class="bottom_right_corner"></div>
</div>
```